# how can Object class in ruby be an instance of it's subclass, class "Class"

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I understand that every class in ruby is an instance of class "Class". Even for Object, Kernel class.

However, I can not wrapper my head around how come Object class, which is an ancestor of class Class, can be an instance of class Class, which is it's subclass.

```
irb(main):018:0* Class.ancestors

=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

irb(main):019:0> Object.ancestors

=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

irb(main):020:0> Object.class

=> Class
```

Comment: You are speaking of Ruby's "object model". It's difficult to explain in a few words. It took the imminent Dave Thomas over an hour to explain it in [this widely-watched video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2sgQ38UDVY). So, makes some popcorn, put up your feet and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you sir! That video was awesome!

Answer (score 0):

`ancestors` method comes under `Module` and it gives `list of modules included in that module`. So, `Class` includes `Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject` modules. And its not like subclass( not extends another class). [Reference.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors)